# Change NSWindow ContentView Height

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, uikit

### Problem

I need to be able to push all the content in a window down by about 75pt. For context, I'm currently trying to build my own custom navigation bar that can be visible across all view controllers (even when a new one is presented), but in order for this to be possible, the content view which houses the root view controller needs to be pushed down. If anyone knows how to change the position/ height of the content view or its relevant constrains, please let me know.

Any help is very much appreciated!

*Please see the image for reference.*

[image: Vector Image that shows a normal Mac window on the left and the window that I want on the right, with the content view pushed down by 75 points.]

Comment: If you use NSToolbar for your custom navigation bar it will drop the contentView automatically.

Comment: Is there a way to add a custom view class inside the NSToolbar?

Comment: >Is there a way to add a custom view class inside the NSToolbar?  Yes, it can be done.  I've used NSImages, NSButtons, NSTextFields, etc.

Comment: The tricky part is adding a UIKit UIView to the NSToolbar though as I'm building a Mac Catalyst app; I am using the Dynamic Library to access Cocoa related variables and views. Do you perhaps no any good tutorials or documentation that might help?

Comment: > any good tutorials or documentation  I have a programmatic cocoa demo of NSToolbar, but no experience with UIKit or Catalyst.

Comment: The other thing is that I plan for this toolbar to also be accessible from iPadOS, not just through the Mac app, and I don't think there is anyway that I could accomplish that through NSToolbar. That's why I need a way to move the window's content view down and then add the custom toolbar as a UIView to the window.

Comment: Usually views are added as a subView to the contentView.  If you drop the contentView I'm not sure how you're going to add the navBar to the bare window.  Have you considered making the navBar a subView of the contentView (and leaving the contentView alone)?

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac the origin of the contentView is at the bottom, left of the window, so if you decrease the view height by 75 the bottom of the view will be pulled away from the menu bar, leaving space for your custom navigation bar.

```
[[window contentView]setFrameSize: NSMakeSize(_wndW, _wndH - 75) ];
```